# Where is lookaround regex supported and where isn't it?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind

Trying to improve my regex skills, I wanted to learn about lookahead and lookbehind expressions. On my Archlinux system I tried the following:

```
a=ab;if [[ $a =~ [a-z](?=b) ]]; then echo "Y";else echo "N";fi
```

Which, as far as I understand it, should match and thus echo out a "Y", but doesn't.

```
echo ab |sed 's/[a-z](?=b)/x/'
```

...also doesn't seem to match.
`grep` doesn't seem to lookaround either, but `pcregrep` does. I also tried several attempts on quoteing and/or escaping the expressions, to no avail.

I'm a little confused, now. Could someone please clarify where lookaround, which doesn't seem *that* exotic judging from the number of mentions in tutorials, can actually be used? Or did I just mess up escaping my expressions?

Comment: I would recommend "Mastering Regular Expressions", by Jeffrey E. F. Friedl; it is my baseline regex reference. I also use (regular-expressions.info) and (rexegg.com) as online references, and (regex101.com) or (regexr.com) as live testers for experimentation. They may be helpful to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lookaround assertions aren't supported by basic or extended posix regular expressions which are available in bash or sed.

A good tool to test is GNU grep which supports the `-P` option for *perl compatible* regular expressions. Like this:

```
grep --color=auto -P '[a-z](?=b)' <<< 'ab'
```

Even a greater resource are online regex testing tools like https://regex101.com/

Comment: So lookaround is basically more of a Perl-Regex feature?

Comment: @some-non-descript-user it's more correct to say that Perl supports lookarounds.

Comment: @some-non-descript-user There are also other regex engines that supports lookarounds like Java, .NET, python etc.. However, POSIX regular expressions doesn't support lookarounds.

Answer (score 1):

You should distinguish between *basic* and *extended* Regular Expressions.

In basic regular expressions the **meta-characters** `?`, `+`, `{`, `|`, `(`, and `)` **lose** their special meaning; They need to be escaped to get their "regex" meaning.

On the other hand, in the *extended* Regular Expressions, these characters get their "regex" meaning.

If you `grep --help`, you'll get:

> `-E`, `--extended-regexp`     PATTERN is an *extended regular expression* (ERE)

Note that grep *doesn't* support look-arounds, it's supported in **pcregrep**.

Comment: Thank you for the heads-up on extended regexs.